# Preserving nodata values when using gdal_translate -scale

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-translate, raster-conversion

I have four 12 - bit Bands in single images which I want to merge to one 8bit Geotiff using GDAL (GDAL 2.1.3)

First thing I do is building a VRT:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 0 -separate bands_merge.vrt band1.jp2 band2.jp2 band3.jp2 band4.jp2
```

Then with gdal_translate I create the tif.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -scale 0 4095 0 255 bands_merge.vrt bands_merge.tif
```

That works just perfect. But as the nodata value of the source files is 0 and all values will be scaled, original values below ~8 will become 0.

My first thought on how to fix that issue was using `-scale 1 4095 1 255` but that does not work because it assigns 1 to all previous 0 values.

How can I make sure that the `-scale 0 4095 0 255` does not create false nodata values ?

Comment: RoVo, if you don't get an answer here, you may want to try asking on the gdal-dev mailing list. https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-April/thread.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using **NODATA**, in this case it is better to use a **mask**:

As the NODATA value is 0, I can easily create the mask with `-co NBITS=1` as everything above a value of 1 will be cut to 1.

```
# Create the mask
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -co NBITS=1 band1.jp2 mask.tif
# Create VRT
gdalbuildvrt -separate bands_merge.vrt band1.jp2 band2.jp2 band3.jp2 band4.jp2 mask.tif
# Create the tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -b 4 -mask 5 -scale 0 4095 0 255 bands_merge.vrt bands_merge.tif
# Remove the temporary files
rm bands_merge.vrt mask.tif
```

Unfortunately QGIS cannot handle GeoTiff mask files yet, but I need it for [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_footprint/imagemosaic_footprint.html#raster-masking).